# Django return response without go through views.py

Tags: django

I'm from PHP, Laravel. I just started learning python and Django.

In Laravel, the route can return a response without going through a controller.

```
'/home', function () {
    return 'hello world';
}
```

Can Django do this too? Without going through views.py? Something like the code below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', function():
        return 'hello world';
    ),
]
```

Comment: Isn't it the same thing, though? You're still using a function to return the response. That's why there's the `views.py` file to hold all your functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `views.py`

Your function can be anywhere and the result will be the same.

The second parameter requires a function to pass the request to and return a response from.

You can use `include` instead to add another list of URLs from somewhere else too.

Answer (score 0):

You got to first import views and than use that view in your URL. For eg:

```
from . import views

path('teacherprofile/', views.teacher_profile_view, name='teacher-profile'),
```